# サイトスピードで検索したURLと結果で出てくるURLが異なる件

Tags: google-sites

サイトスピードでトップページ（日本語）のURLを貼り付け、検索しているのですが、検索結果として出てくるURLは自社サイトの英語ページのURLになってしまいます。（英語ページへリダイレクトされています。）

なぜ英語ページへリダイレクトされるのでしょうか、また、英語ページとトップページ（日本語）でサイトスピードは変わってくるのでしょうか。

ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 一度こちらをご覧になるとよいでしょう。[製品やライブラリの公式サイトからこのサイトを訪れた方へ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2111/)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　最初のところでどんな操作をなさったのかいまいち分かっていないので伺いたいのですが、[google-sites] タグを付けてらっしゃるところから察するに [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=JA) を使ったということでしょうか？

Comment: そのサイトには英語版にリダイレクトされる機能はありますか？